# how can I return may main page from my random image?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to create `recyclerview` apps. Then I create a random image button on my last page (`detailedactivity.java`). When I click button then my image change randomly but at last it doesn't return my main page what can I do?

When I enter my app again I still see the random image there. there is no main page and main image.

Here is my code:

```
Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (mBundle != null) {
    mToolbar.setTitle(mBundle.getString("Title"));
    mFlower.setImageResource(mBundle.getInt("Image"));
    mDescription.setText(mBundle.getString("Description"));
}

showRandomFact();
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        showRandomFact();
    }
});
}

private void showRandomFact() {
    shuffleFacts();

    mFlower.setImageResource(factArray[0].getivImage());
    mDescription.setText(factArray[0].getmFact());
}

Facts f01 = new Facts(R.drawable.a,"hjgbfvjhsdbfvskhbsdıkfvsdkb");
Facts f02 = new Facts(R.drawable.aa,"hjgbfvjhsdbfvskhbsdıkfvsdkb");
Facts f03 = new Facts(R.drawable.aas,"hjgbfvjhsdbfvskhbsdıkfvsdkb");
Facts[] factArray = new Facts[] {
    f01,f02,f03
};
public void shuffleFacts(){
    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(factArray));
}
}
```

Comment: When exactly do you want to return to your man page?

Comment: I have three random image when I click four times then it must return old page. how can ı do it? another problem when I restart my apps. there is still seeing random image.

Comment: by old page do you mean an old image? or that you want to return to your main page?
MainActivity --chosed item from recycle--> DetailedActivity --After 4 clicks--> Main activity?

Comment: no 1-ı start my apps. then I go second page then ı go third page. so my random image button is here, my third page.here is some image, text and  my random image button is also here. then I am starting to click my random image. first click come first random image ...... so when my fourth click it must be return oldpage ( my apps third page.)

Comment: There are some unmatched brackets here. I tried to clean the grammar a bit, but I am not sure if I really get what you mean.